# How to add page url to an HTML Element value

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, url

I'm trying to create a page adaptive share button using the page's current URL (since the page varies from our customer to customer numbers).  In the following code, there is a "script" and in it the element I need to make use the current pages url, "data-url".  Is that possible?

```
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="thispagesurl" data-counter="top"></script>
```

Instead of quotes would I use some sort of variable in javascript or aspx?  I'm really not sure since I honestly don't know that much about js.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do something server side.

It's possible to access and modify the script tag: (Assuming yours is the first script tag on the page)

`document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].setAttribute('data-url', window.location.href)`

However this most likely won't work as scripts will have already loaded their content

Comment: Darn.  I'm guessing I'd have to do something in aspx to create the correct tag.  The file this is in is asp.